# Can servers connect via WiFi instead of an ethernet cable directly to the gateway?

Tags: networking, ethernet, hp, hp-proliant

I am in the process of buying, configuring, and maintaining my first server. This server will be for home use and I will either use this server as a cloud server or as a file server. I am likely going to be an HP ProLiant 360p Gen8. The issue here that I am having is that I live in a household with the gateway in the part of the room my server most likely can not be in. Is it possible to keep this process wireless or will I need a direct connection from my server to the gateway?

After doing some research [here](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c03231393) and [here](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/doc/c04123167) I see that the server (being a base model) has an Ethernet adapter (HP Ethernet 1Gb 4-port 331FLR Adapter), but I see no mention of a WiFi card. If I do have to run an Ethernet to it, I see it will be beneficial to use a switch, still leaving the household their usage and giving me mine. The problem is the gateway is in a troublesome spot and that is why a wireless process is preferred.

Comment: Servers that I have seen in commercial use do not have wireless cards or connectivity. I suggest running Ethernet like you suggested.

Comment: What if I instead choose to create a file server. Would I just need to connect my computer via Ethernet?

Comment: Laptops have the wireless antenna in the lid for good coverage. Computer cases are not amenable to that (I have tried that) so I suggest Ethernet.

Comment: It is POSSIBLE to set up a server to use a wireless connection. But wireless is not a standard or common connection method for servers, and so this often requires additional work to function. Running network cables isn't terribly difficult and will result in a better setup. There are also wireless bridge devices that would "receive" the existing wireless signal and present that to your server through a network cable.

Comment: You certainly can install a WiFi adapter but that particular server does not come with one, most don’t, since wireless is extremely slow compared to 1+ GB Ethernet connections

Comment: Depending on availability and reliability needs go, WiFi could work for a server. But typically one wants the fastest connection possible for a server and that will be wired. Not just for speed but for overall reliability. But for a casual home server? WiFi is fine.

Comment: Are you aware that these servers are quite loud? Tou generally would not want to work or sleep in yhe same room they are in.

Comment: It would be in my closet. After reading some of these comments I am considering an access point and running an Ethernet cord from that to my server. It shouldn't be too loud if it's in my closet (closed door constantly and very airy), right?

Comment: You can try Ethernet over powerline adapters, they are not the fastest, but faster than wifi. I've done it with my server for a while. Ethernet cable is still heaps better, but might be a great solution to delay laying the ethernet cable for a bit.

Comment: Placing this server in your closet will become very loud as the server generates a lot of heat, and a closet can't just dissopate the heat quickly, making the server fans spin more.

Comment: I have seen $50 cases on Amazon for servers of this size, would that dissipate some of the sound? Also, thank you so much for the idea of a power-line adapter!! That is likely the one I am to choose. Would I just need the one gigabit type like this: https://www.amazon.com/Powerline-Ethernet-Adapter-Extender-TP-Link/dp/B084CZMYNM/ref=sr_1_3?c=ts&keywords=Powerline%2BNetwork%2BAdapters&qid=1703260949&s=pc&sr=1-3&ts_id=1194444&th=1 ? Because these are one gigabit ports on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a server 99.9999% of owners will want the best network connection they can get, so fitting a server with WIFI just makes no sense, since generally WIFI is a poor solution compared to a wired connection. WIFI is convenient (no cables), but has a lot of drawbacks in terms of performance.

Because of that servers in general don't come with WIFI (and your model is no exception).

Off course there is nothing stopping you to plug in a USB WIFI dongle in the server if you want, but the performance will be disappointing (even with Wifi 6) compared to a wired 1 Gb/s connection.
As long as a single client is talking to the server it won't be that noticeable with WIFI 4 (or better), but as soon as 2 clients start competing for the WIFI bandwidth speed will drop severely.

Remember that Wifi is a shared medium, which is essentially half-duplex. Only 1 device can talk at any given time. (Not strictly true, I know, but it will apply for most ISP provided residential gateways. These are rarely bleeding edge technology.)

This means that all clients (every WIFI device connected to your gateway by Wifi is a client, including your server) compete for bandwidth on the Wifi. As soon as your brother starts a YouTube video on his laptop the file-transfer you had running between your PC and the server will drop in speed. More users in the house using Wifi, even more drop in speed.
And that is not even considering issues with radio-interference and distance from the gateway that may degrade signal-quality requiring lots of retries, which will also have a major detrimental effect in bandwidth.

So generally Wifi is not a good idea for servers.

If you absolutely want to avoid using network cables consider a set of AV2000 PowerLine adapters between gateway and server. These are reasonably capable these days and usually able to get you a consistent 400-500 mb/s connection and in many cases close to 850 mb/s.
If you happen to have a TV coax cable between the gateway room and were the server is going to be a set of MoCa adapters can also be a good alternative.

Comment: Super helpful information. Now I understand that WiFi is not at all a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with a EIFI adaptor or by adding an AP client to your network.

WIFI encapsulates ethernet frames, so the 2 technologies are quite compatible and converting between them is done at a low level, so it can be invisible to the IP stack.  (that is why most home routers have both ethernet and WIFI devices on the same IP range, and if you traceroute between them they appear directly connected.

WIFI is not great from a speed POV - so it may not be ideal for a file server.

Comment: Is an Ethernet switch also a viable option? I want to try and cause as little change to the rest of the household's connection as possible.

Comment: I dont understand your "switch" question.  Yes a switch will give you very  good connevtivity - but it will require running a network cable.  Unlrss you go tje complex and relatively expensive managed switch way, and set up a router your server will be on the same network as the household. (to me that is desireable if you are running a shared file server - but what are asking???)

Comment: Actually, you're right, I did not realize that when I asked it, I still would need a running network cable so it wouldn't have changed anything. Thank you for your advice thus far!